# Moving hexadecimal to a comp declared variable in cobol

Tags: cobol

Is it possible to assign a string of hexadecimal to a comp or binary declared variable?

Example:
01 COMP-VAR  PIC 9(4) COMP.

MOVE X'04D2' TO COMP-VAR.

should output +1234.

Edited:

Sorry for the lack of the information, I just gave an example. The real scenario is that the data will come from an external source, a dataset. I need to store the data in an alphanumeric variable before I move it to a comp declared variable. My problem is that the data is incorrect when I move the alphanumeric data to the comp variable. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: A `move` statement won't output anything, you'll probably have to `display` it :-) In any case, this is something you can simply try yourself. Was it really necessary to ask the question when that option is open to you?

Comment: It is documented, you can try it, and why would you want to do it? If you want to see 1234 when you eventually get to code a `DISPLAY`, why not `MOVE 1234`?

Comment: Thanks for the abrupt reply. I edited my question to reflect the scenario I am facing.

Comment: Well, you'll need to edit it again. Moving data from a file has nothing to do with hexadecimal literals. Show your definitions, procedure code, and sample data, results you get, results you expect. Include, in full, any messages you get.

Comment: Also, what compiler and OS are you using?

Comment: For other searchers to benefit from your question, it would be useful to update it with respect to the issues raised.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for `REDEFINES`. Redefine the binary value as character, do the assignment
which will not violate any of the assignment rules and then use the binary representation in
subsequent operations. This program illustrates your example:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. EXAMPLE.
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01.
   02 COMP-VAR PIC 9(4) COMP.
   02 COMP-X   REDEFINES COMP-VAR PIC X(2).
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MOVE X'04D2' TO COMP-X
   DISPLAY COMP-VAR
   GOBACK
   .
```

This displays `1234`.

The larger question is why would you need to do this? I suspect that you are attempting to
read a file with multiple record formats in it. Based on some common record identifier you
need to read part of the record as character or as binary. Typically this is done a little
differently in COBOL.

Here is a larger example of what I mean. Suppose you have an input
record that is 3 bytes long. When the first byte is a 'B' it is telling you that the next two bytes should be
treated as a binary (COMP) value. When the first byte is an 'X' you need to read the next two
bytes as text (X) data. As an example this is what two records might look like:

```
 X'E7C1C2' 
 X'C204D2'
```

The first record is a text record containing the value 'AB' (EBCDIC). The second record is binary containing
the value 1234. The program to process these records might look something like:

```
 IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
 PROGRAM-ID. EXAMPLE.
 DATA DIVISION.
 WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
 01  INPUT-RECORD.
     02 REC-TCD       PIC X.
        88 REC-TCD-BIN   VALUE 'B'.
        88 REC-TCD-CHAR  VALUE 'X'.
     02 REC-DUMMY        PIC X(2).
     02 REC-COMP-VAR  REDEFINES REC-DUMMY  PIC 9(4) BINARY.
     02 REC-CHAR-VAR  REDEFINES REC-DUMMY  PIC X(2).
 PROCEDURE DIVISION.
*
*    THIS IS A CHARACTER RECORD
*
     MOVE X'E7C1C2' TO INPUT-RECORD
     PERFORM DISPLAY-INPUT-RECORD
*
*    THIS IS A BINARY RECORD
*
     MOVE X'C204D2' TO INPUT-RECORD
     PERFORM DISPLAY-INPUT-RECORD
     GOBACK
     .
 DISPLAY-INPUT-RECORD.
     EVALUATE TRUE
         WHEN REC-TCD-BIN
              DISPLAY 'REC TYPE: '     REC-TCD
                      ' BINARY DATA: ' REC-COMP-VAR
         WHEN REC-TCD-CHAR
              DISPLAY 'REC TYPE: '     REC-TCD
                      ' CHAR DATA  : ' REC-CHAR-VAR
         WHEN OTHER
              DISPLAY 'UNKNOWN RECORD TYPE: ' REC-TCD
     END-EVALUATE
     .
```

The output from this program is:

```
******************************** Top of Data ***********************************
REC-TYPE: X CHAR DATA  : AB
REC-TYPE: B BINARY DATA: 1234
******************************* Bottom of Data *********************************
```

Look at the INPUT-RECORD definition. The first byte determines how the rest of the
record is to be intrepreted. REC-DUMMY is generally defined as a "generic" buffer area
to be subsequently redefined. In the case of variable length input records, REC-DUMMY
is defined to be as long as the longest record variant so the subsequent REDEFINEs of it
do not "upset" the compiler. All data items following REC-DUMMY begin with the same level
number (02 in the example) and REDEFINE it to the the appropriate format. Subsequent
processing uses whatever record redefinition is appropaiate based on the value in REC-TCD.

Comment: A very reasonable guess. However, from the question `I need to store the data in an alphanumeric variable before I move it to a comp declared variable` unknown as to why there is such a need `My problem is that the data is incorrect when I move the alphanumeric data to the comp variable`, it shouldn't be possible, there should be a compile error, rather than some scrambled result. Wonder what compiler...

Comment: You guessed it write NealB. Thank you very much for your answer.